# How to run xjc -nv in java

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, pom.xml, xjc

I got a pretty large .xsd. I encountered problems to create the classes with xjc. Following error occured:

```
[ERROR] Current configuration of the parser doesn't allow a maxOccurs attribute value to be set greater than the value 5,000.
```

I made a workaround by using xjc -nv .

I'm trying to create the java classes via maven at the moment.

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>xjc</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <!-- The package of your generated sources -->
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Whenever I compile the project, i get an error.

Is there any way to also let maven use the -nv argument?

Comment: [tag:maven-jaxb2-plugin] has the setting `strict`, defaults to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

So the solutions was right in front of my eyes.
You just need to add

```
<arguments>-nv</arguments>
```

to the configuration inside the pom.xml.